# Aliasing vector correctly

Tags: c++, templates, vector, alias

I have not been able to find the answer elsewhere, so I guess I just have to ask this one: I am trying to get an alias for a vector (in which int pointers are stored), as below:

```
    void conversion(Engine * ENGINES) 
    {//The Engine class has a vector of int* as a public data member called SITE
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            vector <int*>* current = &(ENGINES[i].SITE);//the problematic line
            int j_max = current -> size();
            cout << j_max << endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < j_max; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                     if (*current[j][k] == 2)
                    *current[j][k] = 1;
                     if (*current[j][k] == -1)
                    *current[j][k] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that there seems to be an inversion of the indices for the *current[a][b]. I want to be able to use current as a normal vector, but now the indexing is reversed compared to:

```
vector <int*> current1 = ENGINES[1].SITE;
```

so that `*current[i][j] = current1[j][i]` for some reason. Is there a mistake in my syntax?

Comment: Please post the declaration of "SITE". I suspect what you REALLY want is a reference, rather than a pointer. That will allow the compiler to make a better optimisation.

Comment: class Engine
{
public:
 vector <int*> SITE;
}; 
SITE is a vector storing a number of int[3] arrays

Comment: I had previously filled SITE using ENGINES[ENGINE_NO].SITE.push_back(SCORES); in a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is that `[]` has higher precedence than unary `*`. So you're getting `*(current[j][k])` instead of `(*current)[j][k]`, which is what you want.

However you could eliminate that problem by just taking a reference rather than a pointer:

`vector <int*>& current = (ENGINES[i].SITE);` and then just remove your extra loading `*` operators on access to `current`.

Comment: Ahh, you were 5 secs quicker

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but just one follow-up question: why is *(current[i][j]) different from (*current)[j][k]? Does it have to do with how the vector template is implemented?

Comment: `current[i]` is `*(current + i)`, i.e. it treats `current` as an array of `vector<int*>`s and takes `i`th element in that. Yeah, it's that weird.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `[]` has greater precedence than `*` (dereference), so `*current[i][j]` is interpreted as `*(current[i][j])`, which is probably not what you want.

Actually, this idiom of aliasing is commonly expressed as a reference, not a pointer:

```
vector <int*>& current = ENGINES[i].SITE;
```

and use simply `current[i][j]`.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected in my comment, use a reference.

```
vector <int*> &current = ENGINES[i].SITE;
```