# pointer to 2 d matrix syntax

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, syntax

Apologies but I am still quite new to c++ - following on from a previous question [Aliasing vector correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908172/aliasing-vector-correctly) , how are `(*M)[i][j]` and `*(M[i][j])` different (where M is a pointer to an array of integer pointers)?

From what I can tell, it seems that the former is equivalent to `*(*((*MPtr) + i) + j))` and the latter is the same as `*(*(*(MPtr + i) + j))` (where MPtr is a pointer to M). However, I am uncertain as to the meaning of (MPtr + i) - how should I interpret this?

Comment: Do you mean `(*M)[i][j]` for the first one?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(M*)(i][j]
```

That's a syntax error (actually, two). If you meant

```
T (*M)[i][j]
```

instead, then this is the declaration of a pointer to an `i x j` array of elements of type `T`. In contrast,

```
(*M)[i][j]
```

in itself, is an expression in which `M` is either a pointer to an at least 2 dimensional array or a pointer to a pointer to a pointer. Then, `M` is dereferenced, and the resulting array **or** double pointer is indexed, respectively.

Similarly, the expression

```
*(M[i][j])
```

is only valid if `M` is an array of array of pointers (or any class that overloads `operator*`), and it means "dereferencing the pointer which is the `[i][j]`th element of the array `M`".

Edit: the reason why the indexing seems wrong is this (assuming that `M` is a pointer to a two-dimensional array):

```
(*M)[i][j] = M[0][i][j]
```

so this is the `[i][j]`th element of the array (as expected). In contrast,

```
*(M[i][j]) = M[i][j][0]
```

which is wrong when `M` is a pointer to only one array (reading past array bounds invokes undefined behavior).

Comment: I think they meant `(*M)[i][j]` as an expression (so dereferencing `M` first).

Comment: @sftrabbit I added an explanation for that signification as well, thanks.

Comment: Oh, apologies, but yes, (*M)[i][j] is what I meant. M is a pointer to an array of pointers to integers. So what I don't quite understand is why (*M)[i][j] would give a different result from *(M[i][j]) - why would the latter give the [j][i]th element of the matrix instead of the [i][j]th (which is the problem I am encountering)?

Comment: @user1922001 Because those are different expressions. One dereferences the pointer first then subscripts the resulting array, the other one does it the other way around. It does matter whether you take up your parachute and then jump out of the airplane or you jump out first and only then you take up the parachute...

Comment: @H2CO3 So what you are saying is that dereferencing actually changes the indexing of the 2-d array from the i-j ordering to the j-i ordering? Specifically, I am very interested in knowing why the order is now reversed.

Comment: @user1922001 Yes, do the math (pointer arithmetic) and you'll see why.

Comment: @H2CO3: This is exactly what I wanted to ask - I do not know how to do the pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an array the computer stores a pointer to the beggining of the array. That is Mptr. If you write Mptr + i that is goint to be translated as, the memory address of Mptr + size of your Mptr's type * i.

The sintax you wrote is faulty, because you dereferate M[i][j] what is not a memory address, other than that if you write * (M[i]) instead of *M[i], I think that the * has higher precedency so that in the first case M + i gets dereferated and redereferated on the secound M gets dereferated first, and than added i and dereferated again * ((*M) + i), this reverse order will cause your i to behave like a j. write your code the way you think it's more readable, so not like this * (* (* (MPtr + i) + j)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I tried to use the pointer offset notation to understand why *(M[i][j]) is behaving like (*M)[j][i] - you are right that there is some reversal going on, but I do not quite understand your explanation. What do you mean by 'the reverse order will cause your i to behave like a j'? The code is performing the desired way in the first case (*M)[i][j], but in the wrong order in *(M[i][j]) - behaving like i and j are reversed

Comment: @user1922001 I mean if you write *M[i] that will be translated to M[0][i] because *M will be executed first. If you wite *(M[i]) you tell the comuter not to execute *M first, so that will be M[i][0] because M[i] will be executed first. Its realy complicated and related to a stuff called precedency table, that I tought would tell you that * has priority over operator [], unless you define otherwise with the brackets, but acutally it says they will be executed from left to right.